# Install lock on electrical panel

Tags: electrical, lock

I have this Siemens electrical panel and I am looking for a way to install a lock on the panel door so that it can only be opened with a key. Any suggestions? Are there latches that already have built in locks?

[image]
[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge pictures)

Comment: Even if the door is locked, the entire front cover can be removed with two screws. You’ll need some kind of bar that goes across the whole thing that has mounting concealed. That said, should be migrated to diy.stackexchange

Comment: How about ordering the door lock kit mentioned in the panel accessory list?

Comment: To clarify what @Justme said, on the photo you posted, it lists the following product as a lock. Looks like it can be had on Amazon/eBay for $25-30 USD. https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/us/Catalog/Product/?mlfb=US2%3AECQFL2

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight oops, thanks for catching that. I've submitted another edit ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your panel already has the knockout for a lock.  It is immediately above the latch.

See graphic.

[image]

Read the label, it calls out the Siemens part number for a lock kit.

Or you can bring the deadfront to your locksmith and I'm sure they can figure something out.

Remember, it is illegal to deny a tenant access to their circuit breakers.  A locksmith may be able to build a lock that operates on a tenant's key.

Comment: Aren't these panels generally installed *inside* the residence they are connected to?  In which case, the locks on the doors to that residence should be sufficient security.  Adding a lock to the panel would be really annoying to the tenant - even if they have a key it can get lost - I expect most tenants would just leave the key in the lock all the time in order to keep track of it, defeating any possible security advantage.

Comment: Is there a deleted comment somewhere stating that this panel is in a rental?  My first thought was a concern that a kid might decide it was fun to turn off all the lights at once.

Comment: I never stated that this was a rental,even though it is a rental. This panel is for the common area electric and the tenants should not have access to it

Comment: experience gave me a hunch... never hurts to mention it, since StackExchange's whole model is other people with this question finding this on Google.

Answer (score 4):

The door appears to have a breakout formed above the latch. Check with a local Siemens distributor.

Comment: As a comment on the question states, the photo actually shows a list of accessory parts, including the lock kit. https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/us/Catalog/Product/?mlfb=US2%3AECQFL2

Answer (score -1):

I believe I've seen breaker panels with locking latches in schools and some commercial buildings.

You could always add a small padlock hasp on a panel that has no provision for a lock.

Comment: As noted in another answer, this panel _does_ have provision for a lock, and even specifies the exact part number to order. This is, however, reasonable advice for others who may not have a panel door designed to take a lock.